# PHP Encrypt to alphanumeric string and Decrypt to original string for use in URL

Tags: php, encryption

What would be the best way to encode a json array into an alphanumeric string which can be used in a URL querystring?

I need something that is simple, yet not easy to crack. I've read through all the encrypt and decrypt documentation.

I need to encrypt a json array Eg: `{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}` to something like `a14iw58swd33s541dg2k58kv3s4gvkjsdf33s9f3`, so it can be used in a url query string like `http://www.example.com/?v=a14iw58swd33s541dg2k58kv3s4gvkjsdf33s9f3`.

I'll later decrypt this server side. Since it part of a URL, I cannot have something like `ÈƒZ Vì§n‹ØfjÒ šçæ¹ä¯`

What would be an easy and safe way to do this?

Comment: Whatever encrypted string you generate should also go through [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) before being used in a URL

Comment: @Phil If it's alphanumeric, is encoding needed?

Comment: Does the data really need to be stored in the URL? If you want to keep it secret, you are almost always better off storing it on the server and using a token (which could be in the URL, or it could be in the session if it doesn't need to be passed around) instead.

Comment: @Phil, personally, I would have said [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/rawurlencode), but yes, a URL wrapper is a good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Encrypt using any encryption function you see fit, which will produce binary data.
2. Run binary data through [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode) to get an ASCII-only string.
3. ???
4. Profit!
5. Reverse the above steps.

Answer (score 2):

1) Encrypt it using a symmetrical cypher, for example AES. The key you use for it should not be possible to see in any public code (javascript, etc)

2) Run the result of the encruption through base64 encoding, so that it will contain only printable characters.

3) To do the reverse, base64 decode then decrypt using the same key and algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use the strong PHP encryption methods it seems like you've already investigated, and simply encode the result? Let's you pass it via URL without issues, but you don't lock yourself into a specific or weaker encryption method in your attempt to get something that uses a URL-friendly character set.

```
<?php
$ciphertext = /* some encryption code here */

$url_string = urlencode( base64_encode ($ciphertext));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I read the question right, the solution should result in only alphanumeric characters. Base64 does not fit that requirement, as it uses 2 extra characters to encode.

As mentioned earlier, you should use any suitable encryption algorithm first, but then you need a base62 encoder and decoder. There are a few of those on the net. Here is one: https://gist.github.com/Synchro/1139429

However, the questioner's example did not include upper case letters. If lower-case only letters are required, you want a base36 encoding.

On another note, the questioner was asking for what is appropriate for a URL. You can use base64, but you must use a special case, making sure that the extra characters are OK to use. Some base64 implementations include '/' and '+' as the extra 2 characters, and end with a '='. You could change those to '_' and '-', and throw away the '='. See the Encrypt and Decrypt functions here, and notice the blnBase64 flag:

https://github.com/qcubed/framework/blob/master/includes/qcubed/_core/framework/QCryptography.class.php#L116

Answer (score 0):

Note: you are limited to 1024 bytes when passing data through the url. Therefore if your encryption string is truncated (even by 1 character), it will not decrypt correctly.